# Farkas/guards pursuing me glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing a quest for the companions. When I entered Jorrvaskr, Farkas pulled out his sword and began to talk to me. Every time I would try to leave the conversation he would just follow me and try to talk to me again. This lead to me paralyzing Farkas and running away.

By the time I got to the gates of Whiterun he had already gotten up, ran to me and started another conversation. I quickly made it to the gates and exited, he followed me through the gates but I whirlwind sprinted to Shadowmere then attempted to fast travel - which game me the "Can not fast travel when guards are pursuing you" message even though no guards were following me.

I knew Farkas wasn't far behind so I quickly jumped on a carriage and I traveled to the nearest hold which was Dawnstar. Now I can't leave Dawnstar because the same message appears. I have tried to pay off my debt to the Dawnstar guards but it didn't fix the problem. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Has Farkas followed you all the way to Dawnstar?

Comment: In my game, this happened until I completed the Companions quest where you first "turn". I ended up putting up with it and getting rid of a few companions quests, eventually it stopped....

Comment: I weakened him until he fell to the floor, since I was unable to kill him. This allowed me to fast travel away.

Answer (score 8):

Either you kill him or you need to pay off your debts in all the hold capitals. This is because Farkas is programmed to try to arrest you if your bounty is high enough but he lacks the proper dialogue.