# Farkas keeps talking to me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So one day I was at the Skyforge to craft some draugr armor [I completed the Companions Questline so this isn't a mod for draugr armor].  I noticed Farkas, one of the Companions, ran up to me and started to talk to me.  I exited his dialogue but then he keeps talking to me all over again.  I don't have any followers with me.  Farkas keeps talking to me at the same time.  I can acces the Skyforge so he won't talk to me, but when I exit and smithing menu, Farkas keeps talking to me and I keep exiting the conversation. I noticed this is a bug and I don't know how to fix this.  He even keeps following me in Whiterun.  This is more weird I have no bounty in any of the holds, neither a Companions bounty so paying the fine doesn't work even if I commit a crime, and pay the fine.

Since this only happened in Whiterun, and not the other holds; and I don't have bounties on the holds or Companions, it isn't a duplicate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74963/farkas-guards-pursuing-me-glitch).

Comment: Do you have bounties in any of the other holds? Can you still fast travel?

Comment: This happened to me just outside of Solitude, so it isn’t a location specific thing.

Comment: @DGarvanski I don't have any bounties so even if I commit a crime and pay the fine the glitch still happens.

Comment: Try getting really close to him (like, really close, right up to him). Save the game, then restart the game and load your savegame again.

Comment: This glitch is different from the other people who encountered it since I don't have a bounty in the holds of the Companions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the only solutions I had are:

- Killing Farkas [I want a solution without death].
- Leaving a town for a few days [This should reset some things].
  .
- Paying the Companions bounty [I have no bounty in the Companions which is more weird].

I tried doing all the methods. Method 1 and 2 worked, but I'm more satisfied with 2. Once I did it, Farkas was back to normal going back into the mead hall.

Comment: Farkas can't be killed when if you try to kill him he restores his health.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before; it's usually if I steal something from the Companions. They usually kept talking to me after that until I talked to Kodlak to clear my bounty.

Comment: Yeah, but this time I don't have a bounty.

Comment: This kinda more different than what others encountered.